# Spring - catch bean creation exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, configuration

I want to catch bean instantiation exceptions in my code. What options do I have?
One way to do this is to use Java-based container configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public SomeBean someBean() {
    try {
      return new SomeBean(); // throws SomeException
    } catch(SomeException se) {
      return new SomeBeanStub();
    }
  }
}
```

Is that possible to define exception handlers for bean instantiation using Spring using XML-based or annotation-based configuration?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? I would like to catch it, and kill the process, not let the server load it all. My problem is that if some bean is not loaded properly, but others do, you get an inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Very good question:   sure, it is nice to have Spring-Boot manage all the Beans in the initialization phase, but often they do a terrible job of reporting WHY they fail.  I love this question but I have looked for years and cannot find the answer.   It's as-if everyone thinks the answer is unnecessary.

Answer (score 16):

Method `someBean` should catch `SomeException` and then throw [`BeanCreationException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanCreationException.html) with `SomeException` as the cause:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public SomeBean someBean() {
    try {
      return new SomeBean(); // throws SomeException
    } catch (SomeException se) {
      throw new BeanCreationException("someBean", "Failed to create a SomeBean", se);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not suppose to do that. That is the whole point of having Spring create a bean for you. If you are to create your own beans using `new` (like above), why use Spring to create beans for you?

You can indeed allocate object for your self and work along instead of dependency injection and all.

Though I understand the essence behind the question. I think it is best if it fails during the server load time. Reason: The application wont be in an inconsistent state. Say suppose you catch the exception and do some cleanliness, but the other classes would be expecting for that bean to exist which it doesn't.

Hence best it fails at initialization so that the application is consistent. Though I do not know of any other legitimate way of doing.

Comment: Thank you. The question context is the following: if something bad happens during the instantiation of beans (database failure, another external errors), than it should switch to some maintenance mode. Without catching bean creation exceptions it is not possible. Could you please elaborate more how a wrapper can help here?

Comment: The problem here is that 3rd party beans that fail during initialization often have little or no handling of reporting the cause.  Therefore, it would be nice to catch, identify the cause, and return an improved error.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness.

You can also lazy init the bean and catch the exception the first time you use the bean.

spring config:

```
<bean id="a" class="A" lazy-init="true" />
```

In java:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;

public class B {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    A a;

    public void foo(){
         try{
               a.foo();
         } catch (BeanCreationException e){
               // ignore if you want
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you expect failures during bean creation and the bean is not mandatory for the rest of the application (pretty legitimate situation) you can do as you have suggested by catching all failure exceptions in the @Bean method body and returning `null` to indicate that the bean creation has failed.
The bean will not be added to the Spring application context in this case and the context construction will succeed in case if there are no mandatory dependencies on the given bean.