# How can I catch the ProvisioningException that can occur when Spring kafka cannot connect to Producer endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

How can I catch the ProvisioningException that can occur when Spring kafka cannot connect to Producer endpoint during Spring-Boot initialization phase?

I am using the lib called `spring-cloud-stream`,  or in my case, more specifically: `spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka` .

I assume there must be a way to define a config-Bean, or AOP, that might be able to catch the `null error` thrown due to connection problems?    The existing error is not informative enough when connectivity is gone:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:272)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:355)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicIfNecessary(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:329)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:306)
```

I'm talking about the "Bean Creation Phases" documented here: https://reflectoring.io/spring-bean-lifecycle/ which describes how to hook your own code to initialization phases but I want to hook 3rd party code.

NOTE:  The bounty is expired.  An answer outside of the context of Spring Kafka is ok the answer is still relevant to my question.

NOTE: I found another question that also does not provide a good answer: [Spring - catch bean creation exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508342/spring-catch-bean-creation-exception)

Answer (score 0):

you can for example Capture that in ExcepcionHander

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class ExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(value = {ProvisioningException.class})
  public void handleException(ProvisioningExceptione) {
    ....code....
  }
```

I mean the main paoint is to know when do you get this error....
when invoking a method the method should throw it but instead if it is on the initializacion or something like that, it is diferent. I can see such information in your question, please be more specific

Comment: I think the suggestion you have here only catches Exceptions that occur in Rest controllers.   I am trying to catch a ProvisioningException that occurs during Spring initialization BEFORE any rest controller is ever called.    During Spring initialization,  spring-cloud-stream is trying to bind to the Azure resource endpoint, initializing health checks, and fails if the connection info is incorrect.   I'll modify my question to clarify that.

Comment: Yes you are right, it only catches for rest controllers. And what do you want to do if you are able to catch it? I will try to find out how to make that because during initialization of spring beans I have to check first a few things.. I think I know how to do it but I have to test it